# Unable to pass WebDriver object to factory method in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I hope the day finds you well.

I'm still getting comfortable with Selenium and TestNG (and Java in general) and I'm just getting into some of the more interesting stuff.  I'm trying to create tests dynamically using a factory but I'm not able to get the factory to take accept a variable which points at a WebDriver object.  Consider:

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SimpleFactory {
  WebDriver driver;
  String hello = "hello";
  @BeforeSuite
  public void setup(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }

  @AfterSuite
  public void teardown(){
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Factory
  public Object[] factoryMethod(){
    System.out.println(driver);
    System.out.println(hello);
    return new Object[] { new TestClass(), new TestClass() };

  }
}
```

This casts and creates a WebDriver object "driver" as well as a string "hello."  When it gets to the factory the TestClass objects are created and run properly and the system prints out the string that the variable points to.  However, the WebDriver object seems to be null and that's what I get in the console.

This is a tricky one since I don't want my tests to be tied to a particular driver.  Either I'm not passing the object properly or there is something about TestNG factories I don't understand.  Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tried with declaring webdriver as static..

static WebDriver driver;

Thank You,
Murali
http://seleniumtrainer.com/